# Swap the elements of a string and give it back

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and want to write a macro which takes a string for example "platon"  swaps the letters randomly and reproduces a new word for example "lantop". It doesn't have to be a real word.

Comment: What *specifically* is preventing you from implementing this?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/writing-a-function-procedure to get a start

Answer (score 1):

One possible strategy is to go from a string to an array of characters, then shuffle that array (using [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)), join that array to a single string, which is the return value of the function:

```
Function ShuffleString(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim c As String
    Dim chars As Variant
    
    n = Len(s)
    ReDim chars(1 To n)
    
    'load char array
    For i = 1 To n
        chars(i) = Mid(s, i, 1)
    Next i
    
    'now shuffle
    For i = 1 To n - 1
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(i, n)
        If j > i Then 'swap
            c = chars(i)
            chars(i) = chars(j)
            chars(j) = c
        End If
    Next i
    'join and return
    
    ShuffleString = Join(chars, "")
End Function
```

The above function can be used as a worksheet function. Put `Application.Volatile` at the top of the function if you want it recalculated whenever the spreadsheet is recalculated.